# Datamapper: Create Multiple Records with 1 `POST`

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I am using Sinatra and DataMapper to add some rows to multiple tables in the same database after a single `POST` request. 
The problem I'm having is that **this works completely fine locally, but not on the test server, which is using Apache and Phusion Passenger**. On the test server, the form works completely fine and does not throw an error, however only the FIRST of the 3 new records is created (in this example, a User would be created, but not an Order or a Post)

The code I have is:

```
post '/new/quote/guest' do

  g = User.new
   # Add some stuff to the Users table
  g.save

  guestorder = Order.new
    # Do some stuff to the Orders table
  guestorder.save

  i = Post.new
    Do some stuff to the Posts table
  i.save

end
```

On both servers, I am using the same version of Ruby, rvm, and all gems. The only difference is that the test server serves this app with Passenger+Apache.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Edited for clarification, sorry about that

Comment: did you put logs in strategic locations to see that the code has really run?